# cant retrieve values from hash reversal (Perl)

Tags: perl, hash

I've initialized a hash with Names and their class ranking as follows

```
a=>5,b=>2,c=>1,d=>3,e=>5
```

I've this code so far

```
my %Ranks = reverse %Class;     #As I need to find out who's ranked first
print "\nFirst place goes to.... ", $Ranks{1};
```

The code only prints out

```
"First place goes to...."
```

I want it to print out

```
First place goes to....c
```

Could you tell me where' I'm going wrong here?

The class hash prints correctly 
 but If I try to print the reversed hash using

```
foreach $t (keys %Ranks) { 
print "\n $t $Ranks{$t}"; }
```

It prints

```
5
abc23
cab2
ord
```

If this helps in any way

FULL CODE

```
#Script to read from the data file and initialize it into a hash
 my %Code;
 my %Ranks;

 #Check whether the file exists
 open(fh, "Task1.txt") or die "The File Does Not Exist!\n", $!;

while (my $line = <fh>) {   
chomp $line;
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    $Code{$fields[0]} = $fields[1];
    $Class{$fields[0]} = $fields[2];
} 
close(fh); 

#Prints the dataset 
print "Code \t Name\n";
foreach $code ( keys %Code) {
    print "$code \t $Code{$code}\n";
}


#Find out who comes first
my %Ranks = reverse %Class;

foreach $t (keys %Ranks)
{
    print "\n $t $Ranks{$t}";
}
print "\nFirst place goes to.... ", $Ranks{1}, "\n";
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Add another newline so you can see your output clearly.  Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I think you must not have initialized your hash the way you think you have.  If it were, the rest of your code should work as desired.

Comment: Use Data::Dumper and print Class before this statement

Comment: my sure you are declaring hash properly: my %class = (a=>5,b=>2,c=>1,d=>3,e=>5);

Comment: Not gonna help here, but always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check what your data structures actually contain, use Data::Dumper.  `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper(\%Class));`. You'll find un-`chomp`ed newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `chomp`. At present your `$fields[2]` value has a trailing newline.

Change your file read loop to this

```
while (my $line = <fh>) {       
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split /,/, $line;
  $Code{$fields[0]} = $fields[1];
  $Class{$fields[0]} = $fields[2];
}
```